# What type is this switch?

Tags: electrical, lighting

[image]

This switch has 3 screws, but 4 stab-in holes on the back. Is this a 3 way or a 4 way switch? I'm having quite a bit of trouble re-wiring the new switch (got a 4 way, but wondering if this is some type of 3 way - I stupidly didn't take a photo of the wiring beforehand).

The box has 4 wires being used, plus the ground. The top two stab-ins in the photo are labeled "common" (the top right one cracked when removing the wire). Any idea what kind of switch this is?

Comment: It's a "3-way". The top 2 back-stabs are internally connected together.

Comment: Thanks @brhans! Any idea if it's possible to use a 4 ways switch in this configuration, perhaps by tying one of the wires to another?

Comment: Looks like a 2 way switch.  Common and then two other options of where it can switch to. That's 2 way (not 3).  The 4th hole may be LOOP which just loops wires together and is isolated from all the other holes.  Use a multimeter to test my assertion and be sure.

Comment: That is a 3 way switch as Brahms commented (U.S. term other countries call it difere,t) the common is connected together and the bottom 2 are for the travelers.+

Answer (score 1):

### Take the switch you bought back and get a 3-way

That switch is a 3-way switch (the term "common" as part of the labeling for the terminals is a dead giveaway).  Unfortunately, using a four-way as a three-way will probably confuse the next person to work on it, so it's better to take it back and just get a 3-way instead (it'll also get you some of your hard-earned money back as a return credit).

P.S. when you wire the new switch, use the side-screws not the back-stabs. It'll save you a bunch of trouble in the long run.

Comment: Why can’t you use a 4-way as a 3-way? When I draw it schematically and look at it in either position with one screw unused it seems it should work... unless I’m missing something....  I agree he should take it back tho, a 4 way is 4 times (at least) pricier...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two switches that control a light or more than two switches? If you have three or more switches controlling a load it sounds like you need a 4-way switch to me, and the switch itself looks like a four-way with one of the screws removed. The backstab holes are not used by professionals. Are there two sets of wires (cables) in the  box, with two of the wires tied together and pushed into the back of the box?  If that is the case, One set of cables in your box probably goes to one 3-way switch, and the other cable goes to the other 3-way. Use your four way switch, and put one set of wires in one cable on the top two screws and the other cable on the bottom screws. 
Incidentally, it is possible to use a 4 way switch in place of a 3-way switch. Some of the 4-way switches have black or dark screws to differentiate them as one set from the other set, which are brass. And some of the four ways have all four screws in the same brass color. The switch in your picture looks like a four-way with one of the dark screws removed. That could be used as a 3-way switch, which is why everyone here is saying that it is a three-way. The remaining dark screw is common to the other two brass screws. To wire it correctly the common screw has to either have the hot conductor or the switch leg that goes directly to the light. And the brass screws are traveler terminals in which the current can pass alternately between one or the other to get to the other switch.

Comment: 4 way switches have 4 conductors , 3 way have 3, standard on off have 2, that is a 3 way switch.